# Optmize flattening of an array of nested json objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, flatten

Supposed to have an array of objects of objects like

```
[
     {
        "key_set1": {
            int_val: 3,
            arr_val: [
                1,
                3,
                4
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "key_set2": {
            string_val: "foo"
        }
    }
  ]
```

I want to flatten inner objects keys to a new root object to get at the end

```
{
    "key_set1": {
        "int_val": 3,
        "arr_val": [
            1,
            3,
            4
        ]
    },
    "key_set2": {
        "string_val": "foo"
    }
}
```

Assumed that

- This nested structure can have N levels with N > 10
- The structure is a valid json object not a javascript object i.e. it has atomit/non atomic types, not `function` object types;
- The whole input json file can be hundreds of KBytes;
- The work must be done in JavaScript V8 / ECMAScript6;
- The processing time must be of order of milliseconds
- A variant of this mapping, needs to parse the input json object and modify the values (like using `map` array method).

I want to get the most optimized solution for this using built-in methods like `forEach` and/or fast iterators `for`, `while` etc., for the best/worst cases.

Comment: [There is no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: @p.s.w.g wops forgot the question, just added. I want to get this optimized at its best.

Comment: @FelixKling please clarify :)

Comment: Just pointing out that there are no "JSON objects" in JavaScript. Why is JSON even relevant here? The processing is done on JS objects / arrays anyway.

Comment: @FelixKling ah ok you mean about the tags, well the input data it's a json formatted object (see in the requirements list), thanks for the clarification. If it is not clear I can edit it.

Comment: It may be semi-relevant, since we know the objects to be flattened won't contain any members that are Functions, Dates, etc.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be asking for codereview. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ might be a better place to ask this question (please see the help for their guidelines).

Comment: @FelixKling just to be clear, if I'm not going to provide an example, this would be not for codereview? My aim is to get an answer to this, not sure if codereview is the best place by the way thank you.

Comment: If you didn't provide an example, people would ask you to provide what you have already tried ;) Generally speaking, Stack Overflow is for code that doesn't work.

Comment: @FelixKling I partially agree about `code that does not work` there are tons of post with code/without code/etc. but it's a point of view I see. thanks. I will think about it!

Comment: Stack Overflow is mostly for troubleshooting programming issues. The general rule of thumb is, if your code is working correctly as is and the question is simply seeking help optimizing the code in some way (making it faster, more readable, etc.) it's probably a better fit for Code Review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as I understand it correctly, you like to replace the array with an object and take the first level key as the new key for the result object.

```js
var array = [{ "key_set1": { int_val: 3, arr_val: [1, 3, 4] } }, { "key_set2": { string_val: "foo" } }],
    object = {};

array.forEach(function (a) {
    var key = Object.keys(a)[0];
    object[key] = a[key];
});

console.log(object);
```

Comment: I haven't done any benchmarks, but `for(var key in a) { object[key] = a[key]; return; }` may be faster than `Object.keys(a)[0]`

Comment: Is `forEach` generally available more than `map` function?

Comment: @loretoparisi: Probably not, but `.map` has a different purpose (it creates a new array). Don't use `.map` just for iterating an array, that's what `.forEach` does.

Comment: @loretoparisi Why are you concerned about availability? Aren't you using ES6 according to the question?

Comment: @FelixKling yes I know, but `forEach` comes from Mozilla - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for_each...in and it is not in `ECMA` while `map` it is. Maybe fast iterator is better.

Comment: @loretoparisi: You are confusing the [`for each ... in` *loop statement*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for_each...in) with the [`forEach` *array method*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Comment: @4castle good finding. I'm struggling between `node` versions, so I wanted to have safe code through all recent `node` versions.

Comment: @FelixKling ok that makes sense. I have past concerns about `forEach` and avoided to use in the past. I was using `map` since in the real world code it needs to change something.

Answer (score 1):

If you **"want to get this optimized at its best"** - you shouldn't use `Array.map` in your case as it returns a new array.
 You just need to iterate fast through the `list` array and fill the new `flattened` object. 
 Consider the following "optimized" solution:

```
var flattened = {}, len = list.length;
while (len--) {
    Object.keys(list[len]).forEach((k) => (flattened[k] = list[len][k]));
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(flattened, 0, 4));
```

The output:

```
{
    "key_set2": {
        "string_val": "foo"
    },
    "key_set1": {
        "int_val": 3,
        "arr_val": [
            1,
            3,
            4
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps counter intuitively, the original poster's function takes less time to complete than yours does in my informal tests.

Comment: This makes sense. I have seen `while` somewhere for a similar kind of iteration tasks, will it be faster than `for`?

Comment: @loretoparisi, it depends on a number of array items and browser, negative `while` loop should be faster than any "positive" loop

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest supposed we turn to `node` / ECMA6 and json file of hundreds of KB (let's say between 10KB and 100KB).

Comment: @loretoparisi: I think your best bet is to compare some of the methods mentioned here using real data, since, for instance, Roman's code may run much faster on a larger data set.

Comment: @loretoparisi, as Tex mentioned, it would be better to test each approach on real data ... and in different browsers